# MDC crashing with 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIButton applyOutlinedThemeWithScheme:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, swift, material-design, material-components, material-components-ios

I am trying to set a button property like this,
When i add this code it crashes without even displaying the button i have in the main.storyboard.

```html
 let containerScheme = MDCContainerScheme()
        cancelButton.applyOutlinedTheme(withScheme: containerScheme)
```

[image: console]

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. But I was building the UI through code.

```
import MaterialComponents.MaterialButtons
import MaterialComponents.MaterialButtons_Theming

let button = MDCButton()
button.applyTextTheme(withScheme: MDCContainerScheme())
```

The following helped me. I just called the option `Product -> Clean Build Folder`.
After that, the abnormal termination of the program disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

From the error, you can see that `UIButton` does not have a method called `applyOutlinedThemeWithScheme`, which could mean that in your storyboard or XIB, you are using a UIButton instead of a MDCButton.

In your storyboard or XIB, go to Identity Inspector, make sure `Class` is set to `MDCButton`.

Comment: Hey Bill, Thanks for replying I checked i did add the class as MDCButton but it still says the same thing.